# Populate array refPath nested object

Tags: express, mongoose

I am trying to populate a nested object with mongoose. I have a document which contains a list of product or service. I am using refPath to add it dynamically. The problem is when I am trying to populate product/service from path this does not work.

Here my scheme:

```js
const quoteSchema = new Schema({
    other: {type: String},
    list_items: [
    {
        item_id: {
            type: Schema.ObjectId,
            require: true,
            refPath: "type"
        },
        type: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            enum: ['service', 'product']
        },
        quantity: {type: Number},
        desc: {type: String},
        discount: {type: Number},
        unit_price: {type: Number},
        total: {type: Number},
    }
  ],

});
```

Then I have my request :

```js
mongoose.model(model).find({ company_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(company_id), _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id) })
        .populate([{
          path: 'list_items.item_id',
          model: 'list_items.type'
        }])
        .lean()
        .exec( (err, doc) => {

        return res.json({ success: true, payload: doc });
    });
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I find the solution ! I modify the refPath by adding array name so it look like

instead of refPath: "onModel"

now is : "list_items.onModel"

Here is the updated schema :

```js
const quoteSchema = new Schema({    
    list_items: [
        {
            item_id: {
                type: Schema.ObjectId,
                require: true,
                refPath: "list_items.onModel"
            },
            onModel: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
                enum: ['service', 'product']
            },
            quantity: {type: Number},
            desc: {type: String},
            discount: {type: Number},
            unit_price: {type: Number},
            total: {type: Number},
            ref: {type: String}
        }
    ],
    })
```

Then

```js
mongoose.model(model).findOne({ company_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(company_id), _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id) })
        .populate('list_items.item_id')
        
        //....
```